# Самое простое подключение LESS

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Решил освоить LESS какой самый простой метод его подключения что бы я мог сразу видеть изменения стилей на своей странице? ну то есть есть ли варианты что бы мне не надо было тратить время на конвертирование кода less  в сss?

Comment: https://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

Comment: Там очень много всего, и мой английский очень плох, нет ли какой то информации на русском?

Comment: В VS code, есть плагин, `live server` && `easy less`... Или программа `koala`